# Intersection of orbits of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ and $\operatorname{SL}_3$ in $\mathbb{P}^4$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Let $U_d$ be the $(d+1)$-dimensional representation of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbbk)$ i.e. a space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in two variables. A symmetric power projectivization $\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^4(U_1))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^4$. The induced action of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\Bbbk)$ on $\mathbb{P}^4$ preserves rational normal quartic curve $C$. Space of quadrics in that $\mathbb{P}^4$ is $\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^2\operatorname{Sym}^4(U_1))\cong U_8\oplus U_4 \oplus U_0$ where two last terms corespond to the space of quadrics containing curve $C$.

Now I want to use only non-singular quadrics i.e. which is not in discriminant hypersurface of degree 5. But I have no idea how to describe them in terms of degree 4 polynomials. Probably next construction will help somehow.

Consider a Veronese embedding $\nu:\mathbb{P}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^5$. The space of quadrics containig the Veronese surface is parametrized by $\mathbb{P}^5$. There are three $\operatorname{PSL}_3(\Bbbk)$-orbits: Veronese surface, its chordal qubic $D$, and $\mathbb{P}^4\setminus D$. Our quadric $Q$ is smooth iff $Q\in\mathbb{P}^4\setminus D$. Now we take a hyperplane section of the  Veronese surface. Then the surface became rational normal curve $C$, quadrics containing the surface became quadrics containing curve $C$. So chordal qubic is contained in the discriminant. (Hence descriminant consists of qubic and quadric...?)

I can't see the whole picture and connect these facts together due to a lack of my knowledges.

I will be glad for any help